# How to use SQL Server sequences in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, sequence

I'm working on a .NET Core app. While building out my API I ran into an issue with my post endpoint. I want to use a sequence object that exists in our database to keep ids consistent with other tables.

I found a solution online that looked pretty good. I added the following code to my DbContext.

```
    public DbSet<Developer> Developer { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().ToTable("RtpTransaction");

            modelBuilder.HasSequence("HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Developer>()
                .ToTable("Developer")
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE");
        }
```

Then in my controller I set all values other than the Id and I expect that it will automatically populate the Id field with the next value in the sequence.

```
public ActionResult<DeveloperDto> CreateDeveloper(CreateDeveloperDto dto)
        {
            Developer newDeveloper = new()
            {
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedBy = "RtpDeveloper",
                LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastUpdatedBy = "RtpDeveloper",
                DevShort = dto.DevShort,
                DevMedium = dto.DevMedium,
                Status = dto.Status,
                DevClob = dto.DevClob
            };

            _context.Add(newDeveloper);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(newDeveloper.AsDto());
        }
```

However this doesn't work and I get an error telling me Id cannot be null.

I may have misunderstood the article I was reading [here](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-sql-server-sequence-in-entity-framework-core-primary-key/)

Comment: What version of EF are you using? What version of SQL Server? What does the definition of the entity look like? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: If that is the case could you please check in your SQL sequence whether it has generated? Make sure your sequence has been generated successfully.   Once it's generated then call it to use within your table or model. You can [refer to the official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences#basic-usage)